# How to Add robots.txt to a Vaadin 7 Application with CDI-Integration?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, vaadin, cdi, robots.txt

how can I add a robots.txt file to a Vaadin application?

I found nearly nothing related, but what I found states that there is no support for such a file.

I'm using Vaadin 7.1.1 with JBoss 7.1.1 and Vaadin-CDI-Integration.

---

My workaround approach is: By adding `RobotsUI` to the project, the URL `http://localhost:8080/App/robots.txt` becomes accessible.

```
@CDIUI(value="robots.txt")
public class RobotsUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        // Send a response with mimetype 
        // `text/plain` with self defined content.
    }

}
```

---

My problem is: How can I deliver a self-edited, `text/plain` response?

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully published `text/plain` by adding a common `HttpServlet` to the project:

```
@WebServlet("/robots.txt")
public class RobotsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().write("Text...\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it outside of Vaadin, register a filter before vaadin servlet and in case of robots.txt uri return your robots file. Or add some static resource serving servlet registered lets say to /static/* and bind your /robots.txt redirect with [UrlRewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

Comment: Nice idea to solve the issue outside of Vaadin. Thereupon I based my answer which in addition avoids the JAR package. Thanks!